# Update shapefile name with layer name

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, update

I had a layer that I split by fields. The resulting files were given a name. I updated the names of the resulting layers in QGIS but have realized that the shapefiles have not been updated accordingly.

Is there a way to batch synchronize shapefile names with the layer names?

I know I can save as, but that is cumbersome with 75+ layers.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137326/how-to-batch-layer-save-as-process-in-qgis

Duplicate i think.

Comment: It might be faster to re-save the layers than try to sync the names, as there are some ways to automate that like the question you link to (which in turn is marked a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131104/).