# Save as Mapinfo Tabs multiple shp layers

Tags: qgis, batch, tab

i want to convert about 200 shp files to Mapinfo tabs. I found [How to batch "Layer save as"-process in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137326) on running through multiple layers and saving them as shp files. But when i tried to adjust the code for "Mapinfo TAB" it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of GDAL, specifically [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), to do this using a batch file. There is a previous question ([Using ogr2ogr to convert all shapefiles in directory?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25366)) with a good answer as to how you can achieve this for all shapefiles within a given directory.

Answer (score 1):

FME Quick Translator (also known as Universal Translator), a tool that comes with MapInfo Pro, lets you select multiple input files, or a folder with multiple input files.

You can also specify how to deal with this at the output side: Merge into one of keep as separate output files.

[image]